# Decode tfrecords file in hdfs error :tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found:

Tags: pyspark, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to train my model with tfrecords on spark. After saving tfrecord files to hdfs, I meet an error when reading them:

```
2018-08-23 10:16:33.916052: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found:

Â

idxº

·

´

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/model_process/rec_deep_offline/Model/bin/../src/tf_spark/tfspark2.py", line 174, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main)
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/tools/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/model_process/rec_deep_offline/Model/bin/../src/tf_spark/tfspark2.py", line 170, in main
    decode()
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/model_process/rec_deep_offline/Model/bin/../src/tf_spark/tfspark2.py", line 161, in decode
    idx, val = sess.run([idx, val])
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/tools/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/tools/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/tools/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/tools/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/tools/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/tools/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/tools/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 465, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/tools/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 84, in as_text
    return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding)
  File "/nfs/private/liuleifrey/tools/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 1: invalid start byte
```

How can I read tfrecord saved on hdfs with dataset api?

Following is the whole code.

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function


def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def convert_to():
    filepath = "localpath/raw_train"

    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(
            "hdfs://xxx/spark2.tfrecords")
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip().split("||")
            fields_val = line[1].split(" ")
            features_map = {}
            features_map['label'] = tf.train.Feature(
                int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[int(fields_val[0])])
            )
            val = []
            idx = []
            for i in range(1, len(fields_val)):  # feature value
                iv = fields_val[i].split(":")
                id = int(iv[0])
                idx.append(id)
                val.append(float(iv[1]))
            print(val)
            features_map['val'] = _bytes_feature(np.array(val, dtype=np.float32).tostring())
            features_map['idx'] = _bytes_feature(np.array(idx, dtype=np.int32).tostring())
            features = tf.train.Features(
                feature=features_map
            )
            example = tf.train.Example(features=features)
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

        writer.close()

def parse_example_proto_local(example_serialized):
    """
    label:float32
    idx:int32
    val:float32
    :return: label, feats
    """
    feature_def = {
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'val': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'idx': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        }
    p = tf.parse_single_example(
        example_serialized,
        feature_def
    )
    label = p['label']
    #val = p['val']
    #idx = p['idx']
    val = tf.decode_raw(p['val'], tf.float32)
    idx = tf.decode_raw(p['idx'], tf.int32)
    return label, idx, val


def decode():
    file_pattern ="hdfs://xxx/spark2.tfrecords"

    ds = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset([file_pattern])
    ds = ds.map(parse_example_proto_local)
    ds = ds.repeat(1)
    ds.shuffle(100000)
    ds = ds.batch(10)
    iterator = ds.make_initializable_iterator()
    label, idx, val = iterator.get_next()
    config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={"cpu": 0})
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    sess = tf.Session(config=config)
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    idx, val = sess.run([idx, val])
    print(idx)
    print(val.shape)


def main(unused_argv):
    # Get the data.
    #convert_to()
    #train()
    decode()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run(main=main)
```